# How to set an instance variable to Null with Constructor

Tags: java, junit, cobertura

I am testing a method using JUnit and so far I am getting 50% branch coverage for it. The problem I am facing is how to set an instance variable of a class to null which is getting initialized through default constructor. Every time I call the constructor, it initializes that variable and I cannot check it for `Null` condition.

Method under test:

```
public class ClientConfiguration {

private List<IClientFilter> clientFilters;

public ClientConfiguration() {
    clientFilters = new ArrayList<IClientFilter>();
}

public void addFilter( IClientFilter cf ) {
    if( clientFilters == null ) {
        clientFilters = new ArrayList<IClientFilter>();
    }
    clientFilters.add( cf );
  }
}
```

`clientFilters` is never equal to `null` because every time the constructor is called it is initialized to Arraylist().

JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testAddFilter() throws Exception {      
    IClientFilter clientFilter = new EISClientAuthFilter("user1", "pass1");
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();

    clientConfiguration.addFilter(clientFilter);

    assertNotNull(clientFilter);
    assertTrue(clientFilter instanceof IClientFilter);
}
```

Not sure how to set it to `null` so that it goes into the if block and I get 100% coverage on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: By the way: you are interpreting the fact that you can't get test coverage of a branch as meaning that you need to work to cover that branch. An alternative interpretation is that branch is redundant, and should be removed.

Comment: That's true, but I cannot change the method.

Comment: Unless you can change `ClientConfiguration`, you cannot get full test coverage.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to assign a member variable a null value in a constructor:

```
clientFilters = null;
```

or do nothing - its default value is `null` if no other value is assigned.

This means that your constructor would then be redundant: you can simply remove it.

However, I consider it much better practice to assign the non-null value in the constructor, since then you don't have to check if the value is null before using it anywhere else in the class (read about the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)).

You could then just remove the conditional in `addFilter`:

```
public void addFilter( IClientFilter cf ) {
  clientFilters.add( cf );
}
```

This also allows you to make `clientFilters` `final`, which is a good idea if it isn't *really* necessary to change the field.

Comment: You are right Andy and this is what the issue is. I cannot change anything and I was trying to find a way around using the existing method. Do you think of any other way?

Comment: You might be able to do it by reflection... but the point is that there is no point in contriving situations that simply cannot happen because of the way the code has been written to satisfy arbitrary metrics like coverage.

Comment: I just did it through Reflection and it worked. Thanks all.

Comment: That is a very bad practice, I should not have mentioned it. One writes tests to asserts properties of the code, right? Being able to assert that code is redundant is something that has been shown by the test, and so the code should be fixed.

Comment: Do not(!) use Reflection to create an otherwise impossible situation just to drive coverage up. That's a horrible, horrible idea. If a situation cannot occour, then do not abuse your code to create it. In the end, all you get is bad test code to test something that cannot happen and that helps noone, bad test code is even worse then bad code.